# How do you attract views to a unpopular subject?

Tags: discussion, views

It seems most people like to avoid ClickOnce like the plague. I posted [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082410/clickonce-setup-exe-fails-with-deploymentdownloadexception-when-installing-from-n) two hours ago and I have only gotten 9 views. I thought I had a good title

> ClickOnce setup.exe fails with DeploymentDownloadException when installing from network share but the application link works

I did have a older version of the tile

> ClickOnce fails with DeploymentDownloadException when installing from network share, IIS is not installed on the server

and that only got 3 views in a hour.

I thought maybe it was my tags where not getting my post on knowledgeable peoples front pages so I added `.net-4.0` and `c#` but I don't think this is really a 4.0 specific issue and c# is for the program and should not really affect ClickOnce.

I feel the page body is fairly well written but that does not really matter if people are not coming there in the first place. What can I do to get more people to see my question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @James, the bounty suggestion is good, but that is about getting people to visit a question that has existing answers, this is more about getting people to the initial question in the first place.

Comment: What good will "views" as such do you? You only care about views from people who know and use the thing and if it really is "unpopular", there just aren't going to be many...

Comment: @dmckee getting higher total views increases the chance that someone with some relevant knowledge may see it. If I have a poorly worded title or bad tags someone who might know the answer will just skim over the subject as they may not know it is relevant to them or worth their time to explain the issue if they think it is a common issue that has been explained elsewhere (that's why I wanted to include the IIS part of the title at first as a lot of people have this issue when working with IIS but I am not so their answers are not useful to me)

Comment: You get exposure to experts at SO.  They paid for the license.

Comment: I think you're getting plenty of views. You're obviously just spoiled from asking a handful of questions in particularly active tags. They're not all like that. There's no promise of instant answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lack of views is likely related to the level of expertise and interest in the topic. *Lots* of people know and use C#. *Some* people know and use ClickOnce. A good question and title help communicate the problem, but if the topic isn't of interest, people won't click on it.

Ironically (and as you point out) adding irrelevant tags and making the title more vague could actually garner you *more* views, though ultimately the number of useful answers you receive probably wouldn't be affected. (Disclaimer: **don't do that**.)

Comment: I removed the c# tag as I agree with you on the irrelevant tags. I think this may just be a issue of not a lot of experts available.

Answer (score 2):

The more esoteric the problem, the longer you have to wait for an answer.  Even if we forced 500 people to go look at the page, they wouldn't gather anything new than the thousand that already looked at the title, but didn't clickthrough because they didn't believe they'd be able to help.

You might have to wait a day or two for this type of problem, and offering a bounty at that point might help if you still haven't found your answer.

Also, even though you might not be using IIS, the solution might still be to change the mime types - they exist on all major web servers.  If that's the solution, ignore the IIS part, and do the rest of the solution.

Comment: I am not the IT manager of the company, however my first question to the IT manager was `"Does fs1 host a IIS server? I am having trouble deploying the contract flow tool (now that it is moved to \\fs1\contractflowtool\) and from what I am reading it is caused by IIS mucking with the mime types"`, his answer was `"I hate to disappoint but the entire IIS role is not installed on fs1 (nor has it ever been)"` All of the solutions that I have researched say I need to edit the settings on IIS, so if the roll is not installed how can I edit the settings?

Comment: Most people with this problem use IIS.  Think about the solution in terms of general web server setup, and ask your IT manager the appropriate questions. MIME types are a common issue across all webservers.